# How to change the value of 'type' attribute in an input tag ? e.g: 'submit' with 'envoyer'?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change value ,submit with Envoyer. Thanks in Advance.

```
<input class="input-required" type="submit" name="form-submit" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `querySelector` and the `value` property:

```
document.querySelector("input.input-required[value=submit]").value = "Envoyer";
```

`querySelector` is supported on all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Be sure that the `script` element running this code is **after** the `input` tag in the HTML. Usually, just before the closing `</body>` tag is best.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a way to focus that element.  So if it isn't repeated give it an ID.

As for changing the value:

```
document.getElementById("idname").value = "Envoyer";
```

Comment: Thank You very much ! But no option to add an id. It's a page builder